# Can I use Firebase Free Spark Plan for Commercial Use?

Tags: firebase

Can I use Firebase Free Spark Plan for Commercial Use as long as it works for me? If I earn like $25 a month via ads on my website, can I use the Free Spark Plan?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want with Firebase, regardless of payment tier, as long as you adhere to the [terms of service](https://firebase.google.com/terms/).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any limit on how many firebase apps I can create using the free tier?

Comment: You're going to be limited in the number of projects you can create with your account.  That limit may be different for each account.

Comment: If my usage (and user) isn't reaching the limit, will I get the same speed as a paid plan?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no restriction.